# Generate Dynamic User Interface

Tags: java, user-interface, dynamic

I am looking at some framework which will help me to generate the UI Dynamically. What I mean is the UI components to be displayed on the screen and the corresponding validation can be stored in some format like XML. I should be able to generate the UI based on the information in the XML.

That is I will have only one module in my application for displaying UI for various inputs screens which will fetch the data from something like XML

Can anyone suggest if some ready made framework available to achieve this. I was told about Wicket and Vaadin but I am not sure how these will help me achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, it seems like you might be looking for something like http://www.swixml.org/ . This is only a suggestion, not a recommendation: I have not yet used it (although it looks quite interesting, according to the documentation and samples)